# Are the bacteria doing the same photosynthesis as plants do?

Tags: bacteriology, photosynthesis, respiration

I mean Plants during photosynthesis produce  oxygen but Do bacteria also produce oxygen during photosynthesis or produce  other gases?

If yes , how do these bacteria process photosynthesis by producing other gases?

Comment: There are bacteria that do [anoxygenic photosynthesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anoxygenic_photosynthesis) but, afaik, cyanobacteria (which produce oxygen) are the most important phototrophic bacteria on modern Earth. I suggest you do a bit of reading on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Photosynthesis is always about using solar energy to oxidize a mineral molecule and reduce an organic molecule, which becomes an energy source for the photosynthetic cell.

Bacteria and plants have different types of photoreceptors. It is not always the same chlorophyll, maybe even no chlorophyll at all ! The different colours in algae come from the different pigments they are using to do photosynthesis.

Plant cells carry out photosynthesis in chloroplasts, which are organites, whereas bacteria carry it out in their plasmic membranes.

Plants do aerobic photosynthesis, which means they reduce dioxygen into water. Some bacteria do anoxic photosynthesis, which means they can reduce hydrogen sulfide into sulfur.